# How to write a Markdown list with + and - symbols

Tags: markdown

When documenting something I often want to list advantages and disadvantages of something and would like to write a list with + and - symbols:

library x

+ nice design
+ great features
- complex codebase

The best way I found to write this is

```
\+ green<br />
\+ red<br />
\- blue
```

which is not overly good readable in the original markdown language. Someone knows a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can CSS away the bullets for the list:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Then you can avoid the trailing `br` at least:

```
* \+ green
* \+ red
* \- blue
```

Comment: reasonable suggestion @froderik, i use normal bullets in other circumstances however. thx